# Datetime column cannot be pesisted

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL statement to create a table that stores the JSON string data and the event time found in that JSON string.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EventLog] 
(
    [EventID]           INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    [EventTime]         AS CAST(JSON_VALUE(RawEvent, '$.EventTime') AS DATETIME ) PERSISTED,
    [RawEvent]          NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
)
```

However I get the following error below when I run this, I assume SQL Server does not know if the value fits DATETIME? is there a way to get this column defined?

> Msg 4936, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
>   Computed column 'EventTime' in table 'Event' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `CONVERT` with dates and have deterministic behavior as long as you specify certain date styles. As per the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), with the most common JavaScript date formats (since you are converting from JSON), you can use style 126 or 127, which are ISO8601 and ISO8601 with time zone. Your table, then, could be specified like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EventLog] 
(
    [EventID]           INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    [EventTime]         AS CONVERT(DATETIME, JSON_VALUE(RawEvent, '$.EventTime'), 126) PERSISTED,
    [RawEvent]          NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: This worked as described for me and thus is a far better answer than the reply actually marked as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Alas, this is explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/deterministic-and-nondeterministic-functions?view=sql-server-2017):

> CAST  Deterministic unless used with datetime, smalldatetime, or sql_variant.

You may be able to parse the date and reconstruct the value using `datefromparts()` or `datetimefromparts()`.